# Bootstrap 3 drop-down and Rails UJS conflict in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, ujs

I have a sign-up form that submits with `remote: true` and catches `ajax:error` to display validations. In IE8 this functionality is fine on the sign up page, but when the same form is used from a BS3 drop-down, it just follows the `href` on submit without using AJAX.

I have an `<a>` tag that uses `remote: true` to send AJAX requests from a drop-down and it works fine in IE8. The problem only seems to arise with form submits from drop-downs.

This is an obscure problem, but if anyone could help I think it'd help me understand binding JS events better. I added the drop-down code and the relevant JS.

**From the Sign Up page.**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="/signup?locale=en" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign Up</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu signup-dropdown pull-right">

    <div id="signup-form-container">

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/signup?locale=en" class="new_user" data-remote="true" data-type="json" id="signup-form" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="lQcG6WXJO/mcQ/tly+mb+kcEpzY39hdCWhMQkB1VEqA=" /></div>

      ... #fields

      <input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />

    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**users.js**

```
var usersReady = function() {
  var displaySignupResult = function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    //do login stuff
  };

  var signupError = function(event, xhr, status, error){
    //show errors
  };

  $(document).on('ajax:success', '#signup-form', displaySignupResult)
             .on('ajax:error'  , '#signup-form', signupError);
};

$(document).ready(usersReady);
$(document).on('page:load', usersReady);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is about js conflict.
You can solve by listing js file in this format.

in your layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in the application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require purecss-dropdown
//= require_tree .
```

or try this.(but this is not a good practice)

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin1.js', 'admin2.js', 'admin3.js']
```

Hope this will Help.

Comment: I was already using javascript_include_tags, and I tried all sorts of rearranging to no avail. I ended up just disabling the submit action on the forms and using $.ajax to post them myself. As I said, click events worked fine, but not submit ones. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have that problem with devise logging.Yes, the js conflict error.If you use git,you can test it by later version(unproblem one)